# How To Remove Non-Existent/Phantom Yum Repository?

Tags: yum, oracle, rhel7

**TL;DR... I'm replacing public yum repos with an internal one and I can't figure out why two public ones continue to display in "`yum repolist`" when they don't appear in the normal config files.**

I've installed Oracle Linux 7.1 (closely derived from RHEL 7.1) and am switching the system's yum repositories from the public repos to our internal private one.

Oracle Linux 7.1 ships with a default `/etc/yum.repos.d/public-yum-ol7.repo` which contains several repos, the only two which are enabled are "`ol7_latest`" and "`ol7_UEKR3`" which come from `public-yum.oracle.com`.

I delete this file and copy my own own .repo files... `uswulnrepo01_ol7_latest.repo` and `uswulnrepo01_ol7_uekr3.repo`. (`uswulnrepo01` is our internal yum repository).

After I do this I verify with a "`yum clean all && yum repolist`" to verify only my two repositories show up, which they do.

The problem is I end up with 4 repositories...

```
[root@oel7template yum.repos.d]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from ULN.
repo id                           repo name                                                                               status
ol7_x86_64_UEKR3                  Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 3 for Oracle Linux 7 (x86_64) - Latest              158
ol7_x86_64_latest                 Oracle Linux 7 Latest (x86_64)                                                          9,212
uswulnrepo01_ol7_UEKR3/x86_64     Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 3 for Oracle Linux 7 (x86_64) - Latest              123
uswulnrepo01_ol7_latest/x86_64    Oracle Linux 7 Latest (x86_64)                                                          6,784
repolist: 16,277
```

I cannot figure out where `ol7_x86_64_UEKR3` and `ol7_x86_64_latest` are coming from. When I try to get extended info on the repositories (I've removed non-relevant data)...

```
[root@oel7template yum.repos.d]# yum repolist -v
Looking for repo options for [main]
Looking for repo options for [ol7_x86_64_UEKR3]
Repo 'ol7_x86_64_UEKR3' setting option 'enabled' = '1'
Repo 'ol7_x86_64_UEKR3' setting option 'gpgcheck' = '1'
Repo 'ol7_x86_64_UEKR3' setting option 'timeout' = '120'
Looking for repo options for [ol7_x86_64_latest]
Repo 'ol7_x86_64_latest' setting option 'enabled' = '1'
Repo 'ol7_x86_64_latest' setting option 'gpgcheck' = '1'
Repo 'ol7_x86_64_latest' setting option 'timeout' = '120'

Repo-id      : ol7_x86_64_UEKR3
Repo-name    : Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 3 for Oracle Linux 7 (x86_64) - Latest
Repo-baseurl : https://linux-update.oracle.com/XMLRPC/GET-REQ/ol7_x86_64_UEKR3

Repo-id      : ol7_x86_64_latest
Repo-name    : Oracle Linux 7 Latest (x86_64)
Repo-baseurl : https://linux-update.oracle.com/XMLRPC/GET-REQ/ol7_x86_64_latest

Repo-id      : uswulnrepo01_ol7_UEKR3/x86_64
Repo-name    : Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 3 for Oracle Linux 7 (x86_64) - Latest
Repo-baseurl : http://uswulnrepo01.[REDACTED]/yum/OracleLinux/OL7/UEKR3/x86_64/
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/uswulnrepo01_ol7_uekr3.repo

Repo-id      : uswulnrepo01_ol7_latest/x86_64
Repo-name    : Oracle Linux 7 Latest (x86_64)
Repo-baseurl : http://uswulnrepo01.[REDACTED]/yum/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/uswulnrepo01_ol7_latest.repo

repolist: 13,799
```

Notice how the top two unwanted `linux-update.oracle.com` entries don't have a `Repo-filename` value, nor do they match `public-yum.oracle.com` which the default `public-yum-ol6.repo` had.

I've tried everything to remove these entries but I can't figure out how. I've looked around in other yum config files, done some content searches on the `/etc/` directory and I can't find anything relevant. I've even deleted the contents of `/var/cache/yum/`. When I do a "`yum repolist`" after that, the public yum folders re-appear.

I doubt yum itself was modified by Oracle, so these repos have to be in a config file somewhere... How can I figure out where? Is there a command which lists all config files yum reads?

**Edit**

I created a new configuration file "`/etc/yum.repos.d/ol7_x86_64_UEKR3.repo`" as an attempt to permenantly disable the repo:

```
[ol7_x86_64_UEKR3]
name=Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 3 for Oracle Linux 7 (x86_64) - Latest
enabled=0
```

And I get a new error (again, removed unnecessary info):

```
[root@oel7template yum.repos.d]# yum repolist -v
Looking for repo options for [main]
Looking for repo options for [ol7_x86_64_UEKR3]
Repo 'ol7_x86_64_UEKR3' setting option 'enabled' = '1'
Repo 'ol7_x86_64_UEKR3' setting option 'gpgcheck' = '1'
Repo 'ol7_x86_64_UEKR3' setting option 'timeout' = '120'
Repository ol7_x86_64_UEKR3 is listed more than once in the configuration
```

To me, this reinforces the idea that this setting is in a config file somewhere... But how do I find it?

Comment: Oracle is most likely bundling it in yum by default. Run `rpm -ql yum` to see which files oracle's yum rpm contains.

Comment: Do you still believe this even after my edit above where I created a new .repo file to disable the unwanted repo?

Comment: Bundled doesn't mean hardcoded. My point is to list the files bundled in the package like plugins.

Comment: For clarity, I ran this `rpm -ql yum | xargs grep 'linux-update.oracle.com'` and it didn't return anything relevant. The file in your answer below also does not exist in the `yum` package, but probably does in the `rhn` package. Looks like your post disappeared. Adding thoses lines DID fix the problem. If you post again I'll mark as the answer.

Comment: Dunno what happened but it's there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf`

And set :

```
[ol7_x86_64_UEKR3]
enabled=0

[ol7_x86_64_latest]
enabled=0
```

Comment: This solved my problem, I had to add these lines since they didn't exist. Running a `yum clean all && yum repolist` returned just my two internal repositories. Thank you for your help!